# What is the sum of $1^3q + 2^3q^3 + 3^3q^3 +\cdots+ n^3q^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, combinations

What is the sum of $1^3*q + 2^3*q^2 + 3^3*q^3 +...+ n^3*q^n ?$

Comment: I suspect you mean $3^3$

Comment: And I suggest you add your own ideas and thoughts on how to find this sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  Summing a GP,
$$q+q^2+q^3+\cdots+q^n=q\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}=\frac{q^{n+1}-q}{q-1}\ .$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $q$,
$$1+2q+3q^2+\cdots+nq^{n-1}=\{\hbox{something}\}\ .$$
Multiplying by $q$ gives
$$q+2q^2+3q^3+\cdots+nq^n=\{\hbox{something else}\}\ .$$
Differentiating again,
$$1+2^2q+3^2q^2+\cdots+n^2q^{n-1}=\cdots\ .$$
Keep going in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

You are, unless I am mistaken, asking for
$$
1^3q+2^3q^2+\cdots+n^3q^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3q^i.
$$
Note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3q^i=q\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3q^{i-1}=q\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2\cdot iq^{i-1}=q\cdot\frac{d}{dq}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2q^i\right].
$$
Repeating this trick, you can write $\sum i^2q^i$ in terms of $\sum iq^i$, and $\sum iq^i$ in terms of $\sum q^i$. And THAT one, we have a nice and easy formula for.